# Homotopy type of simplicial complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplex, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

I am confused about the following question:

Let $K_{\bullet}$ be a simplicial complex. Let $( \sigma, \tau )$ be a pair of its simplices with $\sigma$ the only codimension $1$ coface of $\tau$.
Prove that $L_{\bullet} = K_{\bullet} \setminus \{ \sigma, \tau \}$ is a simplicial complex of the same homotopy type.

I am confused because I am unsure how $\sigma$ can be the only codimension $1$ coface of $\tau$.
Is it not the case that if $S = \{ v_0, ..., v_n \}$ is a simplex, it must have $n+1$ codimension $1$ faces; $ S \setminus \{v_i\}$ where $ i \in \{0, ..., n\}$

Any further hints on how to proceed would be very helpful; I am aware of basic Algebraic topology and was thinking this may be an application of the simplicial approximation theorem?

Comment: Coface, not face.

Comment: But $\sigma$ is a coface of $\tau$ iff $\tau$ is a face of $\sigma$

Comment: Right, so the assumption is the existence of a simplex $\tau$ such that there exists a unique simplex $\sigma$ which has $\tau$ as a codimension 1 boundary face. Can you think of an example of this situation?

Comment: @MoisheCohen oh I see!